# Centroid in Spherical Coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the solid $G$ bounded above by the sphere $r=a$ and below by the cone $\phi=\gamma$. The centroid of $G$ clearly lies along the $z$-axis ($\phi=0$) and its position $\bar{z}$ is given by $$\bar{z}=\frac{1}{V}\iiint_Gz\,dV$$ where $V$ is the volume of the solid. Since the coordinates of the centroid in spherical coordinates are $(\bar{r},\bar{\phi},\bar{\theta})=(\bar{z},0,0)$, why is $\bar{r}=\bar{z}$ not also given by $$\bar{r}=\frac{1}{V}\iiint_Gr\,dV$$ where $dV$ is the volume element in spherical coordinates? Is this simply because the usual definition of the centroid involving a volume integral of the position is only applicable to cartesian coordinates?

Comment: $(\bar{r},\bar{\phi},\bar{\theta}) \ne (\bar{z},0,0)$. In fact $\bar{\phi}$ is not zero and $\bar{r} = \bar{z} \sec (\bar{\phi})$

Comment: How can we have $\bar{\phi}\neq0$? Since this would imply the solid is not symmetric about the $z$-axis.

Comment: In the integral, spherical coordinates are functions on $G$, and as functions $z$ and $r$ are not the same.

Comment: So if you evaluate the second integral in spherical coordinates, do you obtain the radial coordinate of the centroid?